# Why does this ViewResult fail MSpecMVC's ShouldBeAView assertion?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mspec

I've been following [James Broome's tutorial](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesbroome/archive/2009/09/16/asp-net-mvc-controllers-bdd-the-perfect-match-part-1-the-homecontroller.aspx) to teach myself MSpec and some of the related infrastructure. I'm using the latest version of MSpec, [MSpecMvc](https://github.com/jamesbroome/Machine.Specifications.Mvc), and ASP.NET MVC 2 and I'm not using J.P Boodhoo's libraries.

When I run this test

```
[Subject(typeof(HomeController))]
public class when_the_home_controller_is_told_to_display_the_default_view
{
    static string key;
    static string message;
    static ActionResult result;
    static HomeController home_controller;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        key = "Message";
        message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        home_controller = new HomeController();
    };

    Because of = () => result = home_controller.Index();

    It should_return_the_home_view = () => result.ShouldBeAView().And().ViewName.ShouldBeEmpty();
}
```

I get the following error

> should return the home view : Failed
>   Should be of type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult but is of type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult

When I step through the code it conks in the assertion in this method (in the `ActionResultExtensions.cs` file of MSpecMVC)

```
public static ViewResultAnd ShouldBeAView(this ActionResult actionResult)
{
    actionResult.ShouldBeOfType<ViewResult>();
    return new ViewResultAnd(actionResult as ViewResult);
}
```

Although, I can confirm that `actionResult` is of type `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult`. I've used the same tools on another computer to run other tests but I've not encountered the current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

James Broome's MSpec.MVC extensions use Mspec v0.2. Since you are using Mspec v0.3 there is a mismatch. You should get the source and update the solution to use MSpec v0.3.

Make sure the Mspec.MVC extensions target the same .NET Framwork version as your ASP.NET MVC solution (for example, both are 4.0). That will also depend on which version of MSpec you are using. MSpec v0.3 is compiled against both `.NET 3.5` and `.NET 4.0`

Comment: Hi Sergi, I have indeed got James's source code and performed the substitution to the latest version of MSpec i.e. 0.3 I'll try to ensure that I'm compiling against 4.0. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hey Sergi, what I ended doing was following what you said. I made sure I was compiling against the right versions of the .NET framework and it worked this time. :)

Comment: It's not only about building for the correct .NET Framework version, but more importantly the Machine.Specifications.Mvc has a reference to ASP.NET MVC 1.0, I have a MVC3 project and had the same error even after I changed everything to .NET 4.0 - that was until I found out that James' library had a hard reference to MVC1, after I replaced it with MVC3 and recompiled it started working!

Comment: Would you offer a pull request with your fix to James's repository? Or, since he hasn't made an update in 3 years, if he ignores you, would you publish your own package?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean: Hi Anthony, I'm afraid I no longer have the source code and haven't worked with MSpec in a very long time.

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't realized how old the question was! No harm. I think it's a very searchable problem ;)